# Calling a Method using a string in another class that has already been instantiated

Tags: c#, winforms

The problem I am having is that I would like to call a method from a string.  Here is what I am doing:

Building My List of Strings (Methods) there are three different checkboxList objects in my UI

```
private List<string> MyTest = new List<string>();
private void AddSelectedMethods()
{
        foreach(XName item in BaseTestList.CheckedItems)
        {
            MyTests.Add(item.ToString());
        }
        foreach (XName item in AdminTestList.CheckedItems)
        {
            MyTests.Add(item.ToString());
        }
        foreach (XName item in SubscriberTestList.CheckedItems)
        {
            MyTests.Add(item.ToString());
        }
}
```

Here is the Caller.  If I take out the Reflections call and reference the method directly everything works but I don't want to get into crating a huge list of if else statements.

```
    private void StartSiteTest(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!BackWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
            if (SiteToTest == "estatesales.vintagesoftware.local" || SiteToTest == "localhost")
            {
                es = new EstateSaleTests(site, Sites.First(i => i.SiteUrl == SiteToTest), BasePath, SiteToTest, UseCurrentCompanies);
                foreach (string test in MyTests)
                {

                    // <<<!!!!!!!!  ------ The next line returns null ------ !!!!!!!>>>
                    MethodInfo thisMethod = es.GetType().GetMethod(test);

                    thisMethod.Invoke(es, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

!!!----- EDIT -----!!!

I'm an idiot.  I had the class set to the list of strings but I forgot to rename my Methods Sorry about that.  Yes the Methods were public and they are accessible I just have to rename them to the correct names now.

Comment: Are all methods you try to call defined as public?

Comment: @CBRRacer: your code seems good, there is *probbably* a accessor problem (`public`, `protected`, `private`)

Comment: Does EstateSaleTests have methods that corresponds to the results of all the calls to `item.ToString()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call you use seems pretty acceptable, imo.
The thing is that `GetType().GetMethod()` is able to recover *only* `public` methods.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.module.aspx)  MSDN link.

In order to access methods with different acessors use this [GetMethod(string, BindingFlags)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05eey4y9.aspx) overload.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I just forgot to rename my methods to the proper name.  I had the class changed to that name and everything else just forgot one little detail... good times!!

Answer (score 0):

I notice this has already been well-answered, but the following might still be of use.

Sometimes it is hard to find the method using reflection. You're currently just searching for public instance methods only. What I usually do when finding the method through reflection appears rather hard, is using `GetMethods()` with different binding flags and check by hand whether the expected methods are there.

Note that when you specify binding flags, you *must* also specify `BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance`. In addition, consider the following:

- If the method is an instance method, use `BindingFlags.Static`
- If you don't know whether you have the caption right ("CalcRoot" is different than "calcRoot") than use `BindingFlags.IgnoreCase`
- If you think the method is protected, internal, private or protected internal, use `BindingFlags.NonPublic`
- If you are not sure whether you use a derived type, use `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy`
- If you are uncertain whether what you are looking for is a property, field or method, use `GetMembers` instead.

You can combine all flags with `|` to search for everything. With a little bit trial and error you'll eventually find the set of binding params that you need.

Comment: I actually have an XML list build off of the class names but I have a SuperClass that instantiates all of my sub classes for this test.  I do appreciate it.